# Is there a way to pass credentials in navigator.serviceWorker.register()?

Tags: service-worker, angular-service-worker, service-worker-events

Basically this issue:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17360912/

> Service Worker: Credentials are not sent during registration
>   Author: Yannick S.
>   Created: May 3, 2018
>
> When registering a service worker with navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js') in an authenticated scenario, the request to fetch the service worker omits the Authorization header with the credentials, resulting in a 401 error. (Other browsers send credentials when fetching service workers.) The promise returned by register is rejected with TypeError: invalid argument.

This seems to also apply to Chrome and Firefox, I don't see the Authorization header in the request. There is an option for `register(file, { scope })` but only for specifying service worker scope.

Is there an option like for `links` to pass credentials?
`<link crossorigin="use-credentials">`

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

What does your "fetch" look like?

Try adding: -

credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit

as per fetch [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)